# parallel lines in tikz multigraph

Tags: tikz-trees, graphs

I am trying to make a multi graph, but the edges all overlap one another.
This question has already been asked but I have not been able to find a solution that will work for the format I am using.

I have the following code so far:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,vertex/.style={circle, fill=black!30, draw, minimum size=.3cm, inner sep=0pt}, 
    arc1/.style={draw=red,line width=1.5pt}, 
    arc2/.style={draw=blue,line width=1.5pt},
    arc3/.style={draw=orange,line width=1.5pt},
    arc4/.style={draw=purple,line width=1.5pt},
    arc5/.style={draw=green,line width=1.5pt}]
    \foreach [count=\i] \coord in {(0,0), (1,1), (-1,1), (1,2), (-1,2)}{
        \node[vertex] (p\i) at \coord {\i};
    }

    \foreach [count=\r] \row in {{0,1,0,0,0}, {1,0,0,1,0}, {0,0,0,0,0}, {0,1,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0,0}}{
        \foreach [count=\c] \cell in \row{
            \ifnum\cell=1%
            \draw[arc1] (p\r) edge (p\c);
            \fi
        }
    }
    \foreach [count=\r] \row in {{0,0,1,0,0}, {0,0,0,0,0}, {1,0,0,0,1}, {0,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,1,0,0}}{
        \foreach [count=\c] \cell in \row{
            \ifnum\cell=1%
            \draw[arc2] (p\r) edge (p\c);
            \fi
        }
    }
    \foreach [count=\r] \row in {{0,1,0,0,0}, {1,0,1,0,0}, {0,0,1,0,1}, {0,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,1,0,0}}{
        \foreach [count=\c] \cell in \row{
            \ifnum\cell=1%
            \draw[arc3] (p\r) edge (p\c);
            \fi
        }
    }
    \foreach [count=\r] \row in {{0,0,1,0,0}, {0,0,1,1,0}, {1,1,0,0,0}, {0,1,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0,0}}{
        \foreach [count=\c] \cell in \row{
            \ifnum\cell=1%
            \draw[arc4] (p\r) edge (p\c);
            \fi
        }
    }
    \foreach [count=\r] \row in {{0,1,0,0,0}, {1,0,1,0,0}, {0,1,0,0,1}, {0,0,0,0,1}, {0,0,1,1,0}}{
        \foreach [count=\c] \cell in \row{
            \ifnum\cell=1%
            \draw[arc5] (p\r) edge (p\c);
            \fi
        }
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

I just need each coloured edge to be visible. I am sure it is a simple change to the line `arc1/.style={draw=red,line width=1.5pt},` but everything that I have tried will not work. Any help will be much appreciated.

[image: red and green :)]

Answer (score 2):

You can bend the arcs, each color with a different curvature, by adding

```
bend left=...some number...
```

to the `arc/.style` definitions. Note that you cannot use straight lines (curvature=0), since you have arcs of the same color from A to B and from B to A, of which probably both should remain visible.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,vertex/.style={circle, fill=black!30, draw, minimum size=.3cm, inner sep=0pt}, 
    arc1/.style={draw=red,line width=1.5pt,bend left=10}, % <<<<<<<<<<<
    arc2/.style={draw=blue,line width=1.5pt,bend left=15}, % <<<<<<<<<<<
    arc3/.style={draw=orange,line width=1.5pt,bend left=20}, % <<<<<<<<<<<
    arc4/.style={draw=purple,line width=1.5pt,bend left=25}, % <<<<<<<<<<<
    arc5/.style={draw=green,line width=1.5pt,bend left=5}] % <<<<<<<<<<<
    \foreach [count=\i] \coord in {(0,0), (1,1), (-1,1), (1,2), (-1,2)}{
        \node[vertex] (p\i) at \coord {\i};
    }

    \foreach [count=\r] \row in {{0,1,0,0,0}, {1,0,0,1,0}, {0,0,0,0,0}, {0,1,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0,0}}{
        \foreach [count=\c] \cell in \row{
            \ifnum\cell=1%
            \draw[arc1] (p\r) edge (p\c);
            \fi
        }
    }
    \foreach [count=\r] \row in {{0,0,1,0,0}, {0,0,0,0,0}, {1,0,0,0,1}, {0,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,1,0,0}}{
        \foreach [count=\c] \cell in \row{
            \ifnum\cell=1%
            \draw[arc2] (p\r) edge (p\c);
            \fi
        }
    }
    \foreach [count=\r] \row in {{0,1,0,0,0}, {1,0,1,0,0}, {0,0,1,0,1}, {0,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,1,0,0}}{
        \foreach [count=\c] \cell in \row{
            \ifnum\cell=1%
            \draw[arc3] (p\r) edge (p\c);
            \fi
        }
    }
    \foreach [count=\r] \row in {{0,0,1,0,0}, {0,0,1,1,0}, {1,1,0,0,0}, {0,1,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0,0}}{
        \foreach [count=\c] \cell in \row{
            \ifnum\cell=1%
            \draw[arc4] (p\r) edge (p\c);
            \fi
        }
    }
    \foreach [count=\r] \row in {{0,1,0,0,0}, {1,0,1,0,0}, {0,1,0,0,1}, {0,0,0,0,1}, {0,0,1,1,0}}{
        \foreach [count=\c] \cell in \row{
            \ifnum\cell=1%
            \draw[arc5] (p\r) edge (p\c);
            \fi
        }
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Brilliant!  This is exactly what I have been looking for!  How can I  modify the node creation foreach loop with a list of labels? (instead of just the numbers)

Comment: I figured it out!  Added another foreach loop with the list of labels with and ifnum that compares the index of each of the loops.  
Seriously, though, this is exactly the solution that I have been searching for for the last week, so thanks!